# Get only numbers from string in python

Tags: python

I want to get only the numbers from a string. For example I have something like this

```
just='Standard Price:20000'
```

And I only want it to print out

```
20000
```

So I can multiply it by any number.

I tried

```
just='Standard Price:20000'
just[0][1:]
```

I got

```
 ''
```

What's the best way to go about this? I'm a noob.

Comment: You know `just[0] == 'S'` ,right?

Comment: `"".join(re.findall('\d+', just))` to get all numbers from string

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can use regex:

```
import re
just = 'Standard Price:20000'
price = re.findall("\d+", just)[0]
```

OR

```
price = just.split(":")[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer this price = just.split(":")[1] because the user might enter "200standard price:3000" and using re might not bring the right result. But using 'spilt()' will bring the right result. What do you think?

Comment: from where 200 will come from??,

Comment: The user will give the ticket its plan name, he might give it 2000standard price. It will come from the user input. Hope you get my point?

Answer (score 19):

You can also try:

```
int(''.join(i for i in just if i.isdigit()))
```

Comment: This strings single digits, not individual numbers.

Comment: Don't think so, it will go through finding all the characters that are digits and putting them into a string and casting that string to an int. For example, try "X502YZ", it will return 502. There'd be problems if OP needed to find separate numbers on either side of non-numerics such as "X502Y3" which would return 5023. But this does seem to fulfill OPs requirements.

Comment: This helps me in other assignments

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep it simpler avoiding regex, you can also try Python's built-in function `filter` with `str.isdigit` function to get the string of digits and convert the returned string to integer. This will not work for float as the decimal character is filtered out by `str.isdigit`.

[Python Built-in Functions Filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

[Python Built-in Types str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Considering the same code from the question:

```
>>> just='Standard Price:20000'
>>> price = int(filter(str.isdigit, just))
>>> price
20000
>>> type(price)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Guillius this works doesn't work for python 3.x as filter returns an iterator and not string as in python 2.x

Answer (score 6):

I think [bdev TJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56347796/6266506)

```
price = int(filter(str.isdigit, just))
```

will only work in Python2, for Python3 (3.7 is what I checked) use:

```
price = int ( ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, just) ) )
```

Obviously and as stated before, this approach will only yield an integer containing all the digits 0-9 in sequence from an input string, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This is one of the changes in python 3.x over python 2.x

Answer (score 4):

You could use `string.split` function.

```
>>> just='Standard Price:20000'
>>> int(just.split(':')[1])
20000
```

Answer (score 3):

The clearest way in my opinion is using the `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

just = 'Standard Price:20000'
only_number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', just)
print(only_number)
# Result: '20000'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use RegEx

```
>>> import re
>>> just='Standard Price:20000'
>>> re.search(r'\d+',just).group()
'20000'
```

Ref: `\d` matches digits from `0` to `9`

### Note: Your error

`just[0]` evaluates to `S` as it is the `0`th character. Thus `S[1:]` returns an empty string that is `''`, because the string is of length `1` and there are no other characters after length `1`

Answer (score 1):

A more crude way if you don't want to use regex is to make use of slicing. Please remember that this would work for extracting any number if the **structure of the text remains the same**.

```
just = 'Standard Price:20000'
reqChar = len(just) - len('Standard Price:')
print(int(just[-reqChar:]))
>> 20000
```