# Parsing Out a String

Tags: python, pandas

I have what I think is a complicated request. I'm using a dataframe which looks like this; there are over 50 different names, 35 different shift types with varying formatting/strings (see below for the strings), and dates span for an entire year:

```
Name           Date             Shift
Bob         4/1/2020           ED A 7a-4p
Bob         4/2/2020           zFT ML 6:30p-10:30p
Nancy       4/1/2020           ED FE 3p-1:30a
Nancy       4/2/2020           Charge  2:30p-11:30p
```

I would like to turn this dataset into an output which looks like this:

```
Name     Date          1am 2am 3am 4am 5am 6am 7am.......10pm 11pm Midnight
BOB    4/1/2020                                X
NANCY  4/1/2020                                           X    X      X
BOB    4/2/2020                                X          X
NANCY  4/2/2020        X                                  X    X
```

Notice here that Nancy's shift from 4/1/2020 extended to 4/2 because it went to 1:30AM.

I will focus on the first step of this request and then post again for the second step. What I think the first step should be is to parse out the hours from the `shift` strings in a way which will enable me to calculate the time points between the range while taking into consideration the day in which the hour occurred.

So for example, just looking at Nancy, the dataframe would look like this:

```
Name        Day        Shift_New
Nancy    4/1/2020      3p-1:30a
Nancy    4/1/2020      2:30p-11:30p
```

I found this link which has helped but I was receiving an error when using this code:

```
import re
DF[task_new] = re.findall("\d.*", task)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 're'
```

[Get only numbers from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526367/get-only-numbers-from-string-in-python)

Comment: An important part of providing a [mcve] is to include _code_ for what you've already tried, and how your output was different from what you need. That way we can better gauge how best to help

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your `Shift_new` column, it's as easy as this:

```
dff['Shift_new'] = dff.Shift.str.extract('(\d.*)')
```

This assumes there will never be numbers before the shift times. If that's not the case, please let me know.

### Output:

```
0   Name      Date                 Shift      Shift_new
1    Bob  4/1/2020            ED A 7a-4p          7a-4p
2    Bob  4/2/2020   zFT ML 6:30p-10:30p   6:30p-10:30p
3  Nancy  4/1/2020        ED FE 3p-1:30a       3p-1:30a
4  Nancy  4/2/2020  Charge 2:30p-11:30p   2:30p-11:30p
```

### Explanation:

This is a simple regex. Won't explain exactly what regex are, but I'll tell you what the code does. `\d` means a number, `.` means any character and `*` means zero or more, so `.*` zero or more of any character.

Then, the whole expression means: from the `Shift` column (that is a string), access string methods (using `str`), then find a number and extract this number and everything that comes afterwards.

Comment: Thanks - this works beautifully, I'm new to Python so I was wondering if you could please add annotation to your code to help me better understand exactly what it's doing; specifically, the "str.extract('(\d.*)')" part.

Comment: @Raven What don't you understand? Have you tried checking the Pandas documentation?

Comment: @AMC I have, and like I said I'm very new to Python and Pandas and trying to self teach myself and perhaps not aware of the best resources to find help . This link makes the most sense to me https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001721.htm but its does not explain everything. For example, I'm curious what the "\" , "d" "." and "*" do within the code that Juan provided.

Comment: @Raven That's RegEx, it's not related to Pandas, don't worry. Did you find the [docs for `pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)? In my experience the Pandas docs are quite good.

Comment: Added a little explanation, tell me if you managed to understand