# Finding numbers within certain string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm starting to learn Python and just now getting into regular expressions. I want to figure out what is the best way to search a string to find a number (which can be different lengths) that is always directly following a certain substring.

For example:

```
string = """ this is a very long string with 495834 other numbers;
             if I had the ( 5439583409 );
             Keyword_indicator( 53029453 ); //
             energy to type more and more; ..."""
```

I want to be able to search the string for "Keyword_indicator" which only shows up here, then pull the number within the parenthesis, knowing the number isn't a set length.

```
output = "53029453"
```

Edit - The string has other numbers in it, and the number I'm looking for is always an integer.

Comment: Your number is always an unsigned integer?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only numbers from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526367/get-only-numbers-from-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
string = """ this is a very;
             long string if I had the;
             Keyword_indicator( 53029453 ); //
             energy to type more and more; ..."""
m = re.search('Keyword_indicator.*?(\d+)', string)
output = m.group(1)
```

Comment: Upvoted for providing a regex solution.

Comment: I think this is what i'm looking for thank you for the help.

Comment: You may wish to tighten this a bit as it matches the digits in `Keyword_indicators are needed, call me at 53029453 )`

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use:

```
import re
string = """ this is a very long string with 495834 other numbers;
             if I had the ( 5439583409 );
             Keyword_indicator( 53029453 ); //
             energy to type more and more; ..."""

#This would also match 5439583409 from bla5439583409bla.
re.findall(r'\d+', string)
result will be:
['495834', '5439583409', '53029453']

#If you only want numbers delimited by word boundaries (space, period, comma), you can use \b :
re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string)
result will be:
['495834', '5439583409', '53029453']

#list of numbers instead of a list of strings:
[int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
string = 'biu89'
numbers = ''
for l in string:
    try: numbers+=str(int(l))
    except: pass
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
89
```

note: All numbers will be concatenate to one.

Answer (score -1):

Could could try something similar to the following:

```
>>> import re #import rejex
>>> just='Standard Price:20000' #provide a string
>>> re.search(r'\d+',just).group() #searches string for a digit values and groups
'20000' #result
```

So it would be something to the effect of:

```
string = """ this is a very;
             long string if I had the;
             Keyword_indicator( 53029453 ); //
             energy to type more and more; ...""" #OP provided string
print(re.search(r'\d+', string).group()) #search for digit values in OP provided string, group, and output the result.
```

Comment: The code isn't very clear.